# Develop rich API exposing Stack Overflow functionality

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, api

I would love to see an actual native iPhone app for Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User, etc.  I've actually developed a number of iPhone apps myself, and would certainly be interested and willing in doing the bulk of the legwork, but it would be necessary for the SO team to expose a real API, instead of simply RSS feeds.

Maybe if there's enough demand behind this, we can convince the SO team to build a rich API, which could be useful for many other applications, not just an iPhone app.

Comment: I love my phone and all, but I fear such an app will incent me to attempt to type code on it, and I'm trying to cut down on the stress in my life...

Comment: I agree that I wouldn't want to try typing code into my iPhone, but it would be nice for keeping tabs on questions on the go, or asking one in a pinch when I don't otherwise have access to the internet.

Comment: @bcwood: I know, it was tongue-in-cheek =)

Comment: +1 This would be the best, though an iPhone optimised SO site would be a start. Maybe now Jeff has an iPhone we will see one?

Comment: It would be a win simply to be able to see, in full, the code that others have typed in.  Last time I check, mobile WebKit truncates text marked as "code" at the right margin.

Comment: You can scroll a code region horizontally by dragging with two fingers.

Comment: I've had no problems using SO with the browser on my iPod Touch or my Palm Pre.

Comment: Stack Overflow: There's...not...an app for that.

Comment: If a true iPhone app ever comes out, I'd love for it to include Server Fault, Stack Overflow, Super User, and Meta Stack Overflow in it. The less icons on my Springboard the better. (I have too many already)

Answer (score 14):

I've created a native application for Stack Overflow for anyone who is interested. Try the [iTunes link](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=330493203&mt=8&s=143441) or if you want to know more about how I created it you can check out the [project page](http://www.ioncannon.net/projects/geeqe/). It is limited because I'm using the CC data dump but it is a starting point.

Comment: Anyway to integrate it into the recent activity feed?

Comment: Yes. I'm waiting at this point to see how much real interest there is in the app but that would be one of the next things I try to integrate. On the short list with that would be more profile information and probably push notifications on watched questions.

Comment: Can't you manually update the data dump?  I get csv files from SEDE

Comment: The link to your project page is broken. Could you please edit your post?

Answer (score 9):

The public API beta covers this request, and is available now:

- https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/stack-exchange-api-public-beta-starts/
- https://stackapps.com/

Use the API to build a mobile app or site to your taste!

Comment: Yes, the API is great, but I don't believe that it answers the specific question as it relates to a native iPhone app; you've fulfilled a request but not *this* one, IMO.  This also isn't to say that it's on *you* to fulfill this request, but the status should be `status-declined`, SO did *not* implement a native iPhone app, just the means to one.  That should be considered a separate request with a status of `status-completed`.

Comment: @the well, see http://stackapps.com/tags/iphone+app

Comment: I've modified the title, as it was confusing.  When I originally read the post (before my ♦, *cough*), I read it as "develop an iPhone app", when in reality it didn't, it asked for the API.  Reading it now I see the difference and this answer does fulfill the question (and this *should* be the accepted answer, IMO).

Answer (score 8):

*Disclaimer: This is an advert, but I think people will find it useful*

[Six to Eight](http://sixtoeightapp.com) ([Stack Apps entry](https://stackapps.com/questions/623/six-to-eight-an-iphone-client-now-in-the-app-store)) is a native iOS client for the entire Stack Exchange network. It's free, and uses the API to be up to second synchronised with your Stack Exchange sites and accounts.

Comment: Seems to be the best app for now. Great work. Unfortunately it's read-only.

Comment: @MihailStoynov Every app release before and for the foreseeable future will be read-only. The API doesn't expose any write calls at all.

Comment: @MihailStoynov, see my answer below :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd actually like to see/build a small app that allows me to easily monitor SO status - check to see if there are new comments, view rep, that sort of thing.

Using the site actually ON an iphone is necessarily a little tricky (can't compile and test code on the phone...) so I'm not so fussed about using the desktop.

Jon Skeet posted (on a thread that was to be moved) a URL to retrieve some JSON from his user feed, but alas that doesn't currently appear to be working. I wouldn't mind parsing a little HTML to implement this, but it doesn't feel like the right approach.

Comment: I agree that method certainly doesn't "feel right".  There are plenty of things one could do with screen scraping and piecing together RSS feeds and some JSON, but without a full-out API, it would be difficult to build a native iPhone application the "right" way.

Answer (score 1):

I would find a native iPhone app quite useful.

I will frequently answer some questions and then leave my desk for some time, and an iPhone app with push notifications would allow me to stay on top of the answers and their responses.

However, I can't actually write one even if SO does expose an API (I run Windows)

Comment: You could use Delphi Prism in Visual Studio, Mono and some tools from RemObjects. This allows to build iPhone apps on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: This is an advert, but will hopefully be useful.*

[StackAsk](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stackask/id492631526?ls=1&mt=8) (on [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/2633/stackask-ask-questions-from-iphone-and-ipad-now-on-app-store)) is an app that lets you ask question from your iOS device, so you can type the question offline and it will save it for you, so you can come back later and post it. Also it gives the editor buttons (e.g. Bold, List, insert image) and preview which are missing on the mobile site.

Comment: That is great :)