# Stack Overflow iPhone app

Tags: support, api, open-source, iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Native iPhone app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/native-iphone-app)

Am I the only person who keeps on searching the iPhone app store for a Stack Overflow app? There are probably 100,001 less useful apps out there. Is this something the SO community would be interested in working on as an open source project? Is there an open API we can use? Is this something Joel/Fogcreek/SO developers should work on?

Comment: belongs on meta

Comment: Agreed it belongs on meta, but that or a mobile site would be awesome.

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/native-iphone-app

Comment: No. You aren't the only person: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/native-iphone-app

Comment: All things being equal, I'd rather see a platform-agnostic mobile version of the site. I suspect that would be better received as not *everyone* has or wants an iPhone.

Comment: I agree with AnonJr - is this something that could be done with something as simple as a different stylesheet perhaps?

Comment: Last I heard, there were only about 85K apps on the iPhone, so you exaggerate.  There may only be 84.99K less useful apps.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked into any of this, but I'd think that the extent of SO development could be an API (if they haven't made one already; I haven't looked).  At that point, somebody's going to write a SO app, on the principle that for all X somebody's going to make an X app.  (Hey, it worked with farts and flashlights.)

Answer (score 0):

I've created one. See my answer here: [Develop rich API exposing Stack Overflow functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/native-iphone-app/24074#24074)