# Should Stack Overflow make an iPhone version site app?

Tags: feature-request, api, iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Native iPhone app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/native-iphone-app)

I really want to read SO articles in my iPod Touch, although I can do that now through Safari. But it's not convenient.

Comment: Belongs on meta.

Comment: this has been discussed on the stackoverflow blog I believe..

Comment: I also want stackoverflow to open API so we'll have many so client option

Answer (score 1):

iPhone (and mobile devices in general) should be supported, but I think they'll just expose an API so other people will do it for free.