# iPhone Native App for SO and SEs ( With the Ability to Login and Ask/Answer Questions)

Tags: discussion, iphone, mobile-web

There are a lot of [good SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/native-iphone-app) [iphone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42337/mystacks-stack-overflow-trilogy-iphone-app-free) apps, but none of them seem to allow me to login via my Google Account and start to ask/ answer questions.

Do I miss some entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API at the moment is read-only, so I believe the answer there is "no you didn't miss any". Actually, I find the web UI pretty usable from such devices. There *is* a specific web UI for chat, but it is still, at present, ultimately a web UI (not native).

Comment: @Marc, I've never try web access from mobile, but is OpenID enabled for iPhone access? Seems to me that enabling openid for mobile access is pretty hard technically!!

Comment: @Ngu - I don't fully understand the question; for *web* access, OpenID is just fine. For write access, I guess you'd need a user-specific access key.

Comment: @Marc, I see. But let's say if a native app comes up, is it easy to add OpenID support?

Comment: @Ngu - I'm just thinking aloud here, but you could login to the *web* UI using OpenID to get your private key, right? Or maybe something more elegant, but it is moot since it doesn't exist at the moment.

Comment: @Marc, private key, and that's password right? The whole point of OpenID is to take away the need to remember yet-another-password, but on a mobile device we still need a password. Hmm...

Comment: @Ngu - I'm thinking something more like a twitter client, where the app is responsible for storing the API key (which is *not* a password, btw - *related*, but not the same thing).

Comment: @Marc, thanks for your explanation